# split column into two columns using MySql Update query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have below table `test` which contains datetime column `dt`:

```
test:
         dt
04-15-2017 00:00:00
06-20-2017 10:00:00
07-23-2017 12:00:00
08-28-2017 08:00:00
```

I want to split this column into date(`d`) and time(`t`) as given below:

```
test:
       d            t
    04-15-2017   00:00:00
    06-20-2017   10:00:00
    07-23-2017   12:00:00
    08-28-2017   08:00:00
```

I have written below query to perform the same:

```
UPDATE test SET d=SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, ' ', 1), t=SUBSTRING_INDEX(dt, ' ', -1);
```

But I am getting below error:

```
Error code 1054: unknown column 'd' in field list
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: First you need to add `d` and `t` column in table and then perform update

Comment: Do you have all three columns in your table?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, Thanks, I created `d` and `t` column and it worked.

Comment: What is the data type of the `dt` column?

Comment: May we ask why?